# Run an arbitrary Docker container in Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

### Context

We have a Cypress test suite that we'd like to run as part of our pipeline. Unfortunately the test suite uses too many resources to be ran directly in the pipeline.

A potential solution we arrived at was to build a Docker image with the test suite inside it, and then delegate the actual running of the container to a Lambda.

### The Problem

The problem I'm facing is that with Lambda, if you want to run a Docker container, you have to choose the image up-front when you create the Lambda function. However, since we're building a new image each time we run our pipeline, the image ID isn't static.

### Our Use-Case/Constraints

1. Easily run an arbitrary Docker image
2. Support both sync and async, so we can choose to block until the tests finish

**NOTE:** Using Lambda is not one of our constraints. It seemed like something we could use, given the fact that you can invoke it whenever you need, and you don't need to worry about provisioning.

### What I've Tried

- Docker-in-Docker to try running our Cypress image from within another container. This requires privileged access to the container and it doesn't look like Lambda allows that
- Using a custom runtime to try and run the Docker container manually. Docker isn't included in AWS Linux 2, nor does it look like I can install it.

Comment: If by "our pipeline" you mean CodePipeline, then it seems you would have to develop your own [custom action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-custom-action.html) for this requirement.

Comment: Why is the image ID not static? Typically, the image has a "static" URL and a version. You could use `latest` to always use the latest version. For example: `public.ecr.aws/<registry-alias>/cypress-test:latest`. This should never change and always have the latest image that you build. You might need to redeploy your Lambda every time you update the image. But this could be automated easily in CI/CD as well.

Answer (score 0):

Running lambda custom runtimes require you to publish to ECR.

ECR images will always have different hashes.

However, a single version of the lambda can run at a time.

If you intend to create multiple instances of lambda function with different versions, it will not be possible.

It is better that you dedicate a specific lambda image for a smaller task and run it.

Then you will be able to build each lambda function when your CI completes. After that you can run the lambda function for your requirements.